# Is there a way to show a page's feed without having the user to login using the Facebook Javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook

So, I am currently building a website for a school project, where I would like to display the feed of a Facebook page. But even after nearly two weeks of researching, I haven't found a solution to this problem yet. There are just examples where the user has to log in to their FB account, but that's what I'd like to avoid - I just want to display the feed. I am using the Facebook Javascript SDK, v5.0.

Comment: you have to use a page token, so there is no way to do that without any login. page tokens are generated with a user token.

Comment: Well that's unfortunate. Looks like I'm gonna have to use the Facebook page iFrame. Thanks for your answer.